# How to get the current category url (including the parameters?)

Tags: category, magento-2.2.5

For instance when visiting pages like `example.com/men?p=2`

Already tried with getting the current category from the registry, but then i would get only the url of the category (so only `example.com/men`)

Does anyone know how this could be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

To get the current category url with parameters you can add the UrlInterface to the constructor and call the getCurrentUrl () method in the necessary method:

```
    protected urlInterface;
    public function __construct(
    ... \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface ... 
    ) {
        ...
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        ...
    }
    public function execute()
    {
    ...
       $currentUrl = $this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
    ...

}
```